# Yet another handle backbutton but with example

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, back-button

**Hi,**

I have a MVC application with a form that is dynamicly populated with jquery, when submitting and then hitting back on the browser the dynamic controls will not be visible anymore.

I have tested this code in global.asax :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

But that will not work on all browsers.

I have also thought of just refreshing the webpage when coming from a back button but according to forums on internet this will also not be suported by most browsers?

Its important that the soltion works well with most browsers and also mobile devices.

Yes I do have a "Edit prev Info" button but I can´t prevent users from using the back button.

**BestRegards**

**Edit 1:**

I have found that this webpage : http://www2.blocket.se/ai/form/0 handle the problem nicly(pleas try), the question is how? I have checked but can´t manage to see the solution?

How is it done? Is it a good solution? Or is there another better?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [sessvars.js](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) to store the state of the form in a javascript object and then recheck/repopulate on the document onload event. Not a great solution, but it probably would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can easily fix all your project using another javascript mvvm framework.

It's [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Here you will find few samples: http://www.knockmeout.net/

Than, using one more plugin: [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) you can let users to use the prev or next button on the browser to navigate inside the javascript application steps. [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PKDdG/show/).

And [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) the full tutorial about it.

Comment: Sure! it's perfect for all devices.